# Get recent conversation message from MS Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I am not able to Get conversation nodes from email message using MS graph API. I need recent item of email trail.

My application used Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices to get email and conversations, Now I am upgrading this application to MS Graph API.

Old Code:

```
EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(emailId));
ConversationResponse response = service.GetConversationItems(email.ConversationId,
                                              properties,
                                             null,
                                             null,
                                             ConversationSortOrder.TreeOrderAscending); 
foreach (ConversationNode objC in response.ConversationNodes)
 {
       foreach (Item objItem in objC.Items)
       {
            objItem.Load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.UniqueBody, ItemSchema.Attachments,
                                                    EmailMessageSchema.Sender,
                                                   EmailMessageSchema.Subject));
       }
 }
```

Graph API:

```
Message message = await _client.Users[_config.UserName].Messages[emailId]
                      .Request()
                      .GetAsync();
```

I have not find any property or method to get Conversation Nodes in message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ConversationId and a Filter to get all the messages within a conversation eg something like

```
var ConversationMessages = await GraphServiceClient.Users[UserId].Messages.Request().Filter("conversationid eq '" + Message.ConversationId + "'").GetAsync();
```

If you want the messages returned in Last received order you need to also include the receivedDateTime in the Filter then you can order by that (without getting an error) eg

```
var ConversationMessages2 = await GraphServiceClient.Users[UserId].Messages.Request().Filter("(receivedDateTime gt 2020-08-20) and (conversationid eq '" + Message.ConversationId + "')").OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc").GetAsync();
```